# CentOS with duplicated packages all over system?

Tags: centos, yum

I set up a CentOS 7.2 x64 server on DigitalOcean. Later I updated the kernel following the [DigitalOcean directions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-update-a-digitalocean-server-s-kernel) to `DigitalOcean GrubLoader v0.2 (20160714) CentOS`.

This is one of the simplest server setups imaginable. This is about all I did to get started:

```
yum -y install epel-release
yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum -y install bind-utils curl-devel dos2unix expat-devel gettext-devel libtool lrzip openssl openssl-devel p7zip perl-CPAN perl-devel screen unzip whois zlib-devel
yum -y install httpd mod_ssl certbot-apache
```

I'm sure I did some other things, but that's the gist of it. I used `sudo yum update` from time to time to keep things up-to-date.

I set up some static sites on Apache. I started and enabled `certbot-renew.timer` so that my Let's Encrypt certificates would always be updated.

I knew something was up when I recently received an email from Let's Encrypt saying that my certificates were about to expire. If I just issue the command `certbot` by itself, I get:

```
An unexpected error occurred:
VersionConflict: (certbot 0.19.0 (/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('certbot==0.14.1'))
Please see the logfile '/tmp/tmp3fGvUd' for more details.
```

Oh, but that's just the start. I tried to do `sudo yum update` and got `Multilib version problems found` like [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/rpm-with-different-version-4175621272/). So I followed the directions and removed and reinstalled `grub2-tools` and related packages. Then I tried again. Problems with `NetworkManager`. Then I got problems with `glibc`.

I kept getting all sorts of duplicate package problems, so I found other directions that said to do `sudo package-cleanup --cleandupes`. It found loads of duplicates, but said:

```
Error: Trying to remove "systemd", which is protected
Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

Other sites are telling me that in no way shape or form should I use `--skip-broken`, so I didn't.

Now when I go back to trying to do a simple `sudo yum update` it finds 2 packages to install, 98 to upgrade, and 3 to remove. After happily downloading 100 packages, it starts trying to update things. But a lot of these failed with messages like this:

```
error: Couldn't fork %post(cronie-anacron-1.4.11-17.el7.x86_64): Cannot allocate memory
```

But `htop` shows I'm only using 121M/489M!

I also see things like this:

```
httpd-2.4.6-45.el7.centos.4.x86_64 was supposed to be removed but is not!
```

At this point I figure maybe *something* updated, so I did a `sudo systemctl reboot`.

After the reboot, now I can run `certbot`! I did a `sudo yum check-update` and a `sudo yum update`, and the things that said "was supposed to be removed but is not" seem to have been installed. Although I did get some error

```
Re-declaration of type docker_t
Failed to create node
Bad type declaration at /etc/selinux/targeted/tmp/modules/100/docker/cil:1
/usr/sbin/semodule:  Failed!
```

I rebooted again and tried `package-cleanup --dupes` to see if I still had duplicate package. I have—and loads of them!

```
openssh-clients-7.4p1-13.el7_4.x86_64
openssh-clients-6.6.1p1-35.el7_3.x86_64
nss-tools-3.28.4-1.2.el7_3.x86_64
nss-tools-3.28.4-15.el7_4.x86_64
perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64
perl-5.16.3-292.el7.x86_64
iputils-20160308-8.el7.x86_64
iputils-20160308-10.el7.x86_64
libX11-1.6.5-1.el7.x86_64
libX11-1.6.3-3.el7.x86_64
systemtap-devel-3.0-7.el7.x86_64
systemtap-devel-3.1-4.el7_4.x86_64
…
```

So I tried `sudo package-cleanup --cleandupes` again. It said it would remove 199 packages, and… this time it completed! Now I don't have duplicates! Now no updates are available, so maybe they are all installed! My sites are available! (I will wait to see if certbot updates the certificates automatically.)

Now what I want to know is *how did my system get in a state with all those duplicated packages*? What did I do wrong on such a simple system configuration? And how do I prevent it from happening again!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You end up with duplicated packages when `yum` crashes during an installation.

Since you apparently have a 512MB droplet, you should be aware that `yum` frequently needs more memory than that to complete an upgrade of any significant number of packages.

It's common on 512MB virtual machines for `yum` to run out of memory during installation, and the solution is to set up swap space.

Comment: That's very good information to know, Michael. It's a relief to know that there wasn't some more onerous underlying problem. I'll look into the swap space option. So even though `yum` said it ran out of memory, if it currently says that no updates are available, can I be reasonably certain that everything was resolved and none of the packages are corrupted and/or half-way installed?

Comment: From your description it sounds like you repaired your system successfully. You can be sure by running `yum reinstall "*"` which will cause every currently installed package to be reinstalled. (But keep in mind you'll need the extra memory or swap space for that.)